# Conditional tuple infered from rest parameters

Tags: typescript, types, tuples

Is it possible to infer a Tuple from a key/value mapping ?

Basically it could be a conversion from union type to tuple (like this https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-482330241 )

But I hope for a more elegant and compiler friendly solution like the tuple function suggested by the handbook (http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#example-2)

```js
interface ParamMapping {
    a: boolean;
    b: string;
    c: 'foo' | 'bar';
}

declare function param<K extends keyof ParamMapping>(...name: K[]): ParamMapping[K];
// posible solutions:
// declare function param<K extends keyof ParamMapping>(...name: K[]): ParamMapping[...K];
// declare function param<K extends keyof ParamMapping>(...name: K[]): ...ParamMapping[K];
// declare function param<K extends (keyof ParamMapping)[]>(...name: K): for P of K : ParamMapping[K];
declare function param(...name: string[]): unknown[];

// typed as unknown[]
const p1 = param('baz', 'qux');

// *should be* typed as [boolean, string]
const p2 = param('a', 'b');

// *should be* typed as [string, 'foo' | 'bar']
const p3 = param('b', 'c');

// *should be* typed as [boolean, string, 'foo' | 'bar']
const p4 = param('a', 'b', 'c');
```

[Playground here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=24&pc=33#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApynAtgWTgB31AHNkBvAKGWuTgC5kAjAe2YBsI4QBuKmxhgGcwUErxrIEDAOQxW05AB9k0xhmm8AvhQoATCAjYYUMAK4gEYYMxDJ8GbAB4A0sggAPSCF2DkAawgAT2YYNAdcAiIQYgA+AAoAOiSQbAgGZwBtAF0ASgZ0TAjCEgznLN4Aegq7ZkFgRg5kQXZTKxtBOgoq5H1DY2QzCzbbe0KXN08Ib18A4NCC7Dxi6PikhJSsNORM3PzwpajiDLWyyureoygTc0trEfDxjy8ffyCQsMKDklXk1PTsvLINYLIqHUrlLrnAyXa5DO52B6uJ5TF5xWbvEFfaI5bI-dZ-baAuRQNDId6uPafSIlU56aH9Qa3GwIwqJX6bIQiEq7ZDmPwgZgAdxA2V4kOQYEC+Agulovj5AuF2QoCHaYDsAEZkABeFnYOKqOAAL2kABoVABHUzuaQ5MXdABUggAFsxTGxZYwIA6JVKZXLkBkWOxOCBzcJRNEsiq1XYAEw6vVYA1wM0qRi2+3VJ2u92e72+6WyuC+DIRkjm2TyJTp9TR1UgYR2ADMidG+tUaekCEzOkdLrdHqYBclRYDQdYHC44a50UrcmYCmUhqg0nrsfwABY2+EU12M5We3agA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use [mapped tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays), by changing the first overload signature to this:

```
declare function param<T extends Array<keyof ParamMapping>>(...name: T): {
    [I in keyof T]: ParamMapping[Extract<T[I], keyof ParamMapping>]
};
```

Here, `name` is of type `T`, which is itself an array or a tuple of keys that we need to map over.  If we had `name` as type `K[]` for some key type `K` then the compiler won't keep track of the order, since `K[]` is not a tuple.  Note that the compiler doesn't understand that `I` will always be a numeric-like index so I need to write `Extract<T[I], keyof ParamMapping>` to get something you can index into `ParamMapping` with.

You can verify that it behaves as you want:

```
const p1 = param('baz', 'qux');
// const p1: unknown[]

const p2 = param('a', 'b');
// const p2: [boolean, string]

const p3 = param('b', 'c');
// const p3: [string, "foo" | "bar"]

const p4 = param('a', 'b', 'c');
// const p4: [boolean, string, "foo" | "bar"]
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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)

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you for your answer. This resolve half of the problem because you solution remove the autocomplete from the `param` function. That's what I wanted overload instead of `keyof ParamMapping | string` as `param` args type.
Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, but autocomplete wasn't mentioned in your question, nor did your original version have autocomplete working, so as far as I can tell this resolves the entire problem from the question.  When you have overloads, while you're typing `param("` your IDE will likely choose the `string[]` overload because the string will be `""` which isn't one of the keys... and there will be no autocomplete.   I might circle back to this and work on autocomplete if I have time later.  Good luck!

Comment: Note that the idea of autocomplete with string literals that also accept any string is an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33471) to which there is currently no perfect solution.  `"a" | "b" | string` is just `string` and the compiler forgets `"a"` and `"b"`.  It would be nice if it accepted `string` but still remembered `"a"` and `"b"` to offer in a completion list, but it doesn't.  This is probably a separate question and there might not be a good answer. Good luck again!

Comment: I think yes this is a separate question, but "easy" to answer. Long story short, compiler lost track of an union type of literals if the primitive type from which the literals extends is also in the union.
([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59376316/5252629))

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT *I was actually quite wrong on so many things with my "solution"*

Here a improved and **working** example. A little bit hacky on some parts, but it does the job:

```js
// Base interface that can be latter augmented
interface ParamMapping {
    a: boolean;
    b: string; 
    c: 'foo' | 'bar';
}

// handle every other cases as unknown typed
interface ExtendedParamMapping extends ParamMapping {
    [P: string]: unknown;
}

// hack to handle autocomplete on: "foo" | "bar" | string
type UnknownMapping = string & { _?: never }

// Yes. Named like this.
type Jcalz<T> = {
    [I in keyof T]: ExtendedParamMapping[Extract<T[I], keyof ParamMapping>]
};

declare function param<T extends Array<keyof ParamMapping>, U extends T | UnknownMapping[]>(...name: U | T): Jcalz<U>;

const p1 = param('baz', 'qux');
// const p1: [unknown, unknown]

const p2 = param('a', 'b');
// const p2: [boolean, string]

const p3 = param('b', 'c');
// const p3: [string, "foo" | "bar"]

const p4 = param('a', 'b', 'c');
// const p4: [boolean, string, "foo" | "bar"]

const p5 = param('a', 'baz');
// const p6: [boolean, unknown]

const p6 = param('foo', 'c');
// const p4: [unknown, "foo" | "bar"]
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=39&pc=38#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-n4g64TOiHtgAbIRBjEauILrnRXFyNxTHsH2jy-jhF5Aa2yELmuJQUdBLzUR88xAA)

---

### Original answer

*(answer as post to not flood with code the comment section & because it resolves my question)*

I think I've found how to handle autocomplete with [jcalz answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59366795/5252629) :

```js
interface ParamMapping {
    a: boolean;
    b: string;
    c: 'foo' | 'bar';
}

type UnknownMapping = string & { _?: never }

// Yes. Named like this.
type Jcalz<T> = {
    [I in keyof T]: ParamMapping[Extract<T[I], keyof ParamMapping>]
};

type MappedType<T> = T extends keyof ParamMapping ? Jcalz<T> : unknown;

declare function param<T extends Array<keyof ParamMapping>>(...name: T | UnknownMapping[]): MappedType<T>;
// declare function param(...name: string[]): unknown[]; // not needed anymore

const p1 = param('baz', 'qux');
// const p1: unknown[]
// "basic" string works!

const p2 = param('a', 'b');
// const p2: [boolean, string]
// autocomplete works!
```

No other overload is needed, the original interface stay as is, and autocomplete works. (Inspired from here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29729#issuecomment-460346421 )

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=29&pc=46#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApynAtgWTgB31AHNkBvAKGWuTgC5kAjAe2YBsI4QBuKmxhgGcwUErxrIEDAOQxW05AB9k0xhmm8AvhQpgAnvhQBVEAGsQzAO4g8hEsgC8yYaJCkAZOWQB9APwMQCAA3aGRtCgB6COQATQhBADpkADlsCAATZDZgUxQwAAtgRN0DFAApBDg2AC8AHgAVAD5Hcj5qAG0ASWRQZFy9ZhhkeoBdBnRMXAIiN3aAUQAPEUQwBq6RgBo+iAGhiexbGeJGkYpNXhLDZEOM+tKG5qd65AgliBB0wW3dtAwD6fsvmQFSqdSayAYAFczBZrBd0hAEGwMCgYNCEGBgMwQMh8H8sA0Xm8Pl8AIJQTB6Wr9Qa-SaHEiNRoACgSbJAaQYz2UJnMVhsANmIwAlAwbuk7oYHrwosgEUiUcg0SAMVicXjJqz2ZznCISO0RVCYfyDdxkLKLGBkIEMhlaCA9FhmFAIFQKAhscJcQBGFoa7DM1RwarSLbSACOkIW0mFMuiHpAXvw3qNfOsBp0CaTACY-fjA3BQypGDG45JPVb8NmGO0WOxOCAti4SKd3RXcQBmPOa1RF6QIUuRePt-AdmvNtxbABEcmYU6UyCnaigU9bWcrABZuwHpIWwyWwwPY0Py4nNzW6xwuE29ZPF7P58olxhV0A)

I'll pin [jcalz answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59366795/5252629) as accepted.